# Using Python to insert a particular value through key in Json file

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with key as shown below

```
"container":[]
```

through python code i want to insert value to it and the value is located in a file.
Suppose my value in a file is `{"x":0,"y":0}`

I want output as

`"container":[{"x":0,"y":0}]`

this should happen in a loop and if i have one more text file it should append value as

`"container":[{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":1,"y":1}]`

Please help me with this!!

Comment: What have you tried in code?

Comment: have only tried to read content in json not write @NarendraPrasath

Comment: If you are struggling with a specific step of the problem, ask a concise question about that step, please.

Comment: @DavidWierichs  I just want to know how can we write to a json file..suppose locating a key and inserting value to it.

Comment: That is not one precise question, that is the description of a functionality. Do web search, try building a code, and whenever you get stuck on an error or such, we are more than happy to help you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use json library in python and use that for read from file and write in file and use that like dictionary datatype

By running the following code and paying attention to the type of values, you will realize that functions like dump and load are used to write and read in json file

```
import json

jsn_file_path = r"where you want to create json file or your json file exists there"

dict_a = {"name":"mostafa", "last_name": "vahdani"}
dict_b = '{"name":"mostafa", "last_name": "vahdani"}'

with open(jsn_file_path, "w") as jsn_file:
    json.dump(obj=dict_a, fp=jsn_file, indent=4)


with open(jsn_file_path, "r") as jsn_file:
    jsn_dict_a = json.load(fp=jsn_file)
    print(jsn_dict_a)
    print(type(jsn_dict_a))
    print()


jsn_dict_b = json.loads(dict_b)
print(jsn_dict_b)
print(type(jsn_dict_b))
print()

jsn_dict_c = json.dumps(obj=jsn_dict_b, indent=4)
print(jsn_dict_c)
print(type(jsn_dict_c))
```

And for your answer, you can use a code like the following code

```
import json

your_dict = {"x":0,"y":0}
jsn_file_path = r"where the json file exists"

with open(jsn_file_path, "r") as jsn_file:
    jsn_dict = json.load(fp=jsn_file)
    container = jsn_dict["container"]
    container.append(your_dict)

    jsn_dict["container"] = container

with open(jsn_file_path, "w") as jsn_file:
    json.dump(obj=jsn_dict, fp=jsn_file, indent=4)
```

you can use these sites for more details:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json

https://realpython.com/python-json/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-json-data-in-python/

If you have any other questions, you can leave a comment below for this post
I hope this piece of code help you

Comment: Thank you for the reply..how can i add values to VisualContainer key in this dictionary -------                                                      
[{'id': 0, 'name': 'ReportSection', 'displayName': 'Page 1', 'filters': '[]', 'ordinal': 0, 'visualContainers': [], 'config': '{}', 'displayOption': 1, 'width': 1280, 'height': 720}]

Comment: you can add like this: ```example_dict = [{'id': 0, 'name': 'ReportSection', 'displayName': 'Page 1', 'filters': '[]', 'ordinal': 0, 'visualContainers': [], 'config': '{}', 'displayOption': 1, 'width': 1280, 'height': 720}]```

```example_dict[0]['visualContainers'].append("hello world")```

```print(example_dict)```

Comment: i dont want the contents to be enclosed in double quotes in the result..for example i want it as visualContainers:[500]...but by default quotes are provided ...how can i get rid of quotes returned

Comment: sorry i got confused i want to add again a dictionary to list visualContainers ..how can i do this

Comment: Don't get confused
You can easily do this
As you add a number to a list, now you can add dictionary with a key and value instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

So in Python, you can use the `json` module.

Read json data from your file and store it in a Python dictionary.
From there, editing the dictionary is simple, and you can later save the altered dictionary to a file using the json module again.

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
import json

with open(base_file_path, 'r') as f:
    base_dict = json.load(f)

for file_path in appendable_data_dict_paths:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        do_dict_manipulation(base_dict, json.load(f))

with open(base_file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(base_dict, f)
```

By the way, make sure you style your Json correctly (json must start and end with { and } respectively).

Comment: Thank you ..How can i insert data to visualContainers in this dictionary----
 [{'id': 0, 'name': 'ReportSection', 'displayName': 'Page 1', 'filters': '[]', 'ordinal': 0, 'visualContainers': [], 'config': '{}', 'displayOption': 1, 'width': 1280, 'height': 720}]